# How can i patch out a parameter from a function that calls a method?

Tags: python, mocking, decorator, patch

Hello I am pretty new to unit testing and therefore I got a big issue with unittest.mock.
My Project consists of different modules. 
My first module is General:

```
general.py


def do_something(item, collection): 
    # some more code that i want to test
    try:
        collection.insert_one(item)
    except:
        print("did not work")
```

My second module ist my_module.py

```
mymodule.py

import general
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client['db']
collection = db['col']

item = 
  {
    "id": 1
  }



def method:
    general.do_something(item, collection)
```

Now I want to test the do_something(item, collection) method from general.py, and therefore I want to mock the collection.insert_one(item). I did not find a possible solution for this.
I tried it with patch, but my Problem is, that the parameter collection (which is a pymongo Collection) is a parameter that calls a function. How can i now manage to mock collection.insert_one?

My target is to extract collection.insert_one and set a MagicMock into it. And this Magic Mock should have the possibility to crash to check if the except part works or to not crash to check if the try part workes.

```
TestGeneral.py
import unnittest

class TestGeneral(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch()
    def test_general():
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need to mock anything. You just need to provide an argument that supports `insert_one`, and a way to test if the result of calling that does what you expect. Anything else would be testing `insert_one` itself, not `do_something`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need a mock here, you could just create a class that has a similar functionality.

```
TestGeneral.py
import unnittest

class TestGeneral(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_general_success():
        assert general.do_something(collection(), None)

    def test_general_failure():
        with self.assertRaises(Exception): 
            general.do_something(collection(fail=True), None))

class collection:
    def __init__(self, fail=False):
        self.fail = fail

    def insert_one(self, item):
        if self.fail:
            raise Exception
        return True
```

Then you can also check the stdout to make sure a print is used on success

Comment: but collection in my case is not a class. Collection is a Collection from a MongoDB... Then your solution does not work right?

Comment: Well since you were planning on mocking it it doesn't really matter. If you want to test an actual MongoDB collection then you would have to create one, but it seems like you just want to test your exception handling, which would work with this method

Comment: okay, you are right, but is there also a possible way to test with mocking? :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, you can't mock local variables, so the best way to do it if you had to use mock would be to create a function that gets the `collection` object and mock that.

Comment: I will add a second answer that will cover mocking

Answer (score 1):

If you had to use mock for some reason, this method could work

TestGeneral.py
import unnittest

```
class TestGeneral(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('{your path}.my_module.MongoClient')
    def test_general_success(mock_mongo):
        mock_mongo.return_value = {'db': None, 'col': collection()}
        assert general.do_something(None, None)  # None here since the collection is mocked anyway

    @mock.patch('{your path}.my_module.MongoClient')
    def test_general_failure(mock_mongo):
        mock_mongo.return_value = {'db': None, 'col': collection(fail=True)}
        with self.assertRaises(Exception): 
            general.do_something(None, None))

class collection:
    def __init__(self, fail=False):
        self.fail = fail

    def insert_one(self, item):
        if self.fail:
            raise Exception
        return True
```

The downside to this is that you have now mocked the entire MongoDB, meaning any other uses of it (i.e client) will also be mocked

Comment: As you can see this is pretty similar to the other function and still uses the class as the mock. This is needed because you need something that will raise exceptions properly. You could edit the class to be more suited to your needs but this is a basic version